# logstash - regex matching username extension

Tags: regex, logstash, pcre, elastic-stack

I'm trying to tag usernames that come across like john.smith.fg or jane.doe.hg - matching specifically on the .aa - .zz.  not all usernames will have this, some may be john.pa.smith which wouldn't match, neither should ms.galore.

I have this in my logstash filter

```
if [UserName] =~ /^[a-z+].*\.[a-z][a-z]$/ {
  if "fg" in [UserName] { 
    mutate {gsub => ["[user_acct_type]","normal","probation"]}
  } else if "hg" in [UserName] {
    mutate {gsub => ["[user_acct_type]","normal","intern"]}
  } #fg hg
} #username
```

if I run the regex through regex101 it matches just fine - but logstash doesn't recognize the matching.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is matching now?

Comment: actually I just need to close/delete this.  it's matching the regex fine it doesn't like the IF under it.

Answer (score 0):

it wouldn't' let me just close it without adding an answer.  I do feel like the topic and regex provided would be beneficial to someone else (I couldn't find it readily at first).  but no complaints if someone wanted to ditch this question entirely.